# JAXB + JERSEY. How to unmarshall multiple namesapaces

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, xlink

I have trouble with the namespaces.
I need to unmarshall from a public api (Prestashop).
This api has xml as xlink type like below:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<products>
<product id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/prestashop/api/products/1"/>
<product id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/prestashop/api/products/2"/>
</products>
</prestashop>
```

the api for each product is:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<product>
<id>
<![CDATA[ 1 ]]>
</id>
<id_manufacturer xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/prestashop/api/manufacturers/1">
<![CDATA[ 1 ]]>
</id_manufacturer>
<id_supplier xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/prestashop/api/suppliers/1">
<![CDATA[ 1 ]]>
</id_supplier>
<id_category_default xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/prestashop/api/categories/3">
<![CDATA[ 3 ]]>
</id_category_default>
</product>
</prestashop>
```

I generated two package which contains pojo classes for each XML.
I'd like to get the properties of any product given an id from products list.

I've got a product with the namespace in @XMLSchema, but this namespace is static just for one path. I known that's not the way to do it.

Below, my client class.

```
public class ClientPrestashop{  

    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClientPrestashop.class.getCanonicalName());
    private final String pass = "LA4DKY4AVJUODHCX0H0XH8E7EROV05J6";
    private final String url="http://LA4DKY4AVJUODHCX0H0XH8E7EROV05J6@localhost:8080/prestashop/api/";

    public Object getPrestashopPackageProducts(String path, Class<?> clase) throws JAXBException, Exception{

        ClientConfig config= new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(pass, ""));

        WebResource webresource = client.resource(url + path);
        ClientResponse response = webresource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);

        mostrar(response.getStatus());

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clase);

        //Crear XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter(url+path,true);

        //El XMLReader será encapsulado en nuestro XMLFilter.
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xr);

        //Modificar UnmarshalerHandler como ContentHandler en XMLFilter 
        Unmarshaller unmarshall = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshall.getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        //Parse del XML
        InputSource sr = new InputSource(response.getEntityInputStream());
        filter.parse(sr);
        Object presta = unmarshallerHandler.getResult();

        return presta;
    }
```

Here you have the code: https://github.com/JorgeP86/webservice.git

Can you help me, please?

Comment: I think you may be able to adjust the expected schema url in the generated package-info.java. There should be an annotation in there. 

If not you may be able to use Castor which is a little less strict on qualified name restrictions.

Comment: Thank you, Jamel Toms. My package-info didn't generete automatically from given xml schema. I must did generating a new package and then fill with the following code `@XmlSchema(namespace="http://LA4DKY4AVJUODHCX0H0XH8E7EROV05J6@localhost:8080/prestashop/api/products/1")`

elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,. Then I genereted POJO classes with JAXB.

Comment: But this namespace is just for one product if I want .../products/2 I need to change it. How to get all namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;

    @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
    private String href;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html